# I think I should awarded with "Unsung Hero" badge

Tags: discussion, badges

**Tenacious:** Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total

**Unsung Hero:** Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total

I have [26 total accepted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1699833+isaccepted%3A1), [15 are upvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1699833+isaccepted%3A1+score%3A1..1000) and [11 are zero scored](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1699833+isaccepted%3A1+score%3A0).

```
more than 10 and 25% of total

26*25% = 7
```

Why I was not awarded with **Unsung Hero** ?

Comment: I think the answers need to be at least a week old

Comment: I believe it's 25% of your total answers, not 25% of your accepted answers

Comment: @RichardTingle nope, not [according to this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/152859): *and have those zero-score accepted answers account for at least 25% of all your **accepted** answers*

Comment: Relevant part of the above linked faq is "Only accepted answers at least ten days old are considered", as @Ral also mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The query for the badge looks up all accepted answers that are 10 days old, and are not self-accepted, deleted or community wiki, then checks that at least 10 of those are at 0 points and if that makes for more than 25% of the qualifying accepted answers.

Comment: So I have to wait for 10 days and not giving answer to get the badge :)

Comment: Well, not necessarily. Although, you should try not to get your answers accepted :P I too have to wait for another 7-8 days for my gold badge :D

Comment: ok I will accept your answer when I will get the gold badge :D

Comment: lol okay. :) Btw, try this (with your userid)
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3a355610%20isaccepted%3a1&tab=votes